# Append unit type to the result of a calculation in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I've been refactoring my CSS to a SASS style sheet recently. I'm using the [Mindscape Web Workbench extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) for VS2012, which re-generates the CSS each time you save your SCSS. I started with code similar to this:

```
/* Starting point: */
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; /* 24px ÷ 16px */ }
```

Then I tried to refactor it first to this:

```
/* Recfator: */
h1 { font-size: (24px / 16px)em; }
```

But this unfortunately produces:

```
/* Result: */
h1 { font-size: 1.5 em; }              /* doesn't work, gives "1.5 em" */
```

Notice the **extra space**, which I don't want there. I've tried several alternatives, here are a few:

```
h1 { font-size: (24/16)em; }           /* doesn't work, gives "1.5 em" */
h2 { font-size: 24 / 16em; }           /* doesn't work, gives "24/16em" */
h3 { font-size: (24px / 16px) * 1em; } /* works but "* 1 em" feels unnecessary */
h4 { font-size: (24em) / 16; }         /* works, but without "px" it's not 
                                          really conveying what I mean to say */
```

I've also tried these variants with variables (because I want those anyways), but that didn't change the situation much. To keep the examples in this question sleek I've left out variables. However, I'd happily accept a solution that relies on using variables (in a clean way).

I've gone through the [relevant SASS documenation on '/'](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash), and appreciate that this is a tough one for SASS because the '/' character already has a meaning in basic CSS. Either way, I was hoping for a clean solution. Am I missing something here?

PS. [This blogpost](http://erskinelabs.com/calculating-ems-scss/) does offer one solution, using a user defined function. That seems a bit heavy-weight though, so I'm interested if there's "cleaner" solutions in line with my attempts above. If someone can explain the "function approach" is the better (or even only) solution then I'll accept that as an answer too.

PS. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15513395/419956) seems to be about the same thing, though that one specically wants to do further calculations. [The accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514279/419956) is my third workaround (multiplying by `1em`), but I'd love to know if there's a different (cleaner) way if I'm willing to forego the ability to do further calculations. Perhaps the method mentioned in said question ("interpolation") is useful for me?

---

***Bottom line:*** how can you cleanly append the unit type (e.g. `em`) to the result of a calculation in SASS?

Comment: What does doing the math gain you (other than slower compilation and arguably lower readability)?  Not every browser starts with a 16px font-size (historically, Opera used a smaller base font-size than other browsers... and users have been known to increase or decrease their font-size on purpose).

Comment: Once I replace the numbers with variables, the math will show meaning and/or intention, making it self-documenting instead of "magic". As I mention in the question, I left out variables in my examples to keep them simple.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question:  what does doing the math gain you?  Regardless of what you ultimately use (variables vs hard coded values) `24px / 16px * 1em` has lower readability than `1.5em`.

Comment: I prefer `$target-header-font-size / $body-font-size` over just `1.5em`, because the first documents what kind of proportions I'm aiming for. It also allows me to tweak the baseline variables of my design, which automatically proportionally scales the dependent values. The "compile" time of the CSS is negligible (a tiny fraction of a second), which -for me- is totally worth it. (PS. I use a reset style sheet to set a target baseline font-size for the page.)

Comment: Setting the font-size on the body element also sets the baseline of the project (`body { font-size: 100% }` and `h1 { font-size: 1.5em }` -- or use `rem` if you feel you must).  There's no advantage to what you're doing over using what vanilla CSS has offered pretty much forever.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree ;-). Worst case this makes my question part of an XY-problem. By now, Y (appending units to calculations) has become a challenge in itself for me.

Comment: @cimmanon Your help and answer are appreciated, but I feel my question is not quite a duplicate. I explicitly mention "multiplying by `1em`" is a workaround I prefer *not* to use, and in this question's context I do *not* care about being able to do further calculations. Though you might disagree, the answer to the question as I asked is in fact interpolation. (And given that interpolation is *not* the answer to that other question, I don't see how they can be duplicates...). Please consider unmarking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Multiplication is not a "workaround", it is the correct answer and the maintainers of Sass will tell you the exact same thing.

Comment: Your remark is fine as a comment and/or competing answer, but perhaps not as a justification for the gold-badge-dupe-hammer. If I had known about the other question at the time of asking this one I still might've asked this one. I try to reflect this with my latest edit, and based on that edit I've also cast a reopen vote asking the community if they'd be willing to reopen it.

Comment: You have done a great disservice to Sass authors everywhere by reopening this question.  It is now the top result on Google.  Your "preferred method" is the worst possible way to append a unit to a number and only causes confusion when it doesn't work the way they expect down the road.

Comment: If you disagree with the most upvoted and accepted answer you should *write a better answer*, not rant in comments about it. - Explain why/when interpolation is the wrong tool of choice and/or tell folks one of the methods I mentioned already is the preferred way.

Comment: @cimmanon Thank you for responding with an answer. It might be best (least confusing) for future visitors if our comment-conversation here is wiped by a moderator. Should you agree, please flag this comment of mine for custom mod attention to ask them to clear all of them.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**The only way to add a unit to a number is via arithmetic**.

To perform operations like concatenation (eg. `1 + px`) or interpolation (eg. `#{1}px`) will only create a **string** that *looks* like a number.  Even if you're absolutely 100% certain that you're never going to use your value in another arithmetic operation, you *should not do this*.

More important than not being able to perform arithmetic operations, you won't be able to use them with other functions that expects a number:

```
$foo: 1; // a number
$foo-percent: $foo + '%'; // a string

.bar {
    color: darken(blue, $foo-percent); //Error: "1%" is not a number!
}
```

> $amount: "1%" is not a number for `darken'

There is nothing to be gained by casting your numbers to strings.  Always use arithmetic (multiplication by 1, or addition by 0) to add a unit:

```
$foo: 1; // a number
$foo-percent: $foo * 1%; // still a number! //or: $foo + 0%

.bar {
    color: darken(blue, $foo-percent); //works!
}
```

Output:

```
.bar {
  color: #0000fa;
}
```

Here's a mixin I wrote as part of my Flexbox mixin library that will choke if you pass in a string (for those not familiar with Flexbox, the original specification only allows integers for the `box-flex` property.  `flex: auto` or `flex: 30em` cannot be made compatible with the comparable `box-flex` property, so the mixin doesn't bother trying)

```
@mixin flex($value: 0 1 auto, $wrap: $flex-wrap-required, $legacy: $flex-legacy-enabled) {
    @if $legacy and unitless(nth($value, 1)) {
        @include legacy-flex(nth($value, 1));
    }

    @include experimental(flex, $value, flex-support-common()...);
}

@mixin legacy-flex($value: 0) {
    @include experimental(box-flex, $value, $box-support...);
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: Just seconds after finding your answer here (unit conversion) I googled if Sass had a switch construct and I landed here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/554#issuecomment-18304635 Figure the odds, good sir. :D And thanks!

Comment: For percent and a sass variable $var, I used: #{$var}#{"%"}.

Comment: Maybe changing "The only way to add a unit to a number is via **arithmetic**." → "... is via **multiplication**." would be more clear. I tried **addition** everywhere before realizing that it was exactly what *not* to do...

Comment: @Atav32 actually the **addition** is also possible, if you have `$foo: 1;` then you can use `$foo-percent: $foo + 0%` to convert it to percent like as `$foo * 1%`

Comment: TL;DR `$foo-percent: $foo * 1%;`

Comment: Next time please put the solution at the top.

Answer (score 46):

You can try either of these:

```
font-size: $size * 1px;
```

or

```
font-size: $size + unquote("px");
```

Where `$size` is the result of your calculation.

Comment: The second method worked out for me very well. I found out that `unquote("px");` is the key here. If we don't apply `unquote`, the `px` will be rendered within quotes and the browser will be unable to render the value correctly. Hence applying `unquote` is essential.

Comment: Note that font-size: $size + px; (without any quotation around the px) is also possible which is so simpler than the second method! see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350676/2803565) below

Answer (score 22):

Choose the method you prefer

```css
$font: 24px;
$base: 16px;
```

No variables

```css
.item1 { font-size: #{(24px / 16px)}em; }
```

Using only variables

```css
.item2 { font-size: #{$font / $base}em; }
```

One variable

```css
.item3 { font-size: #{$font / 16px}em; }
.item4 { font-size: #{24px / $base}em; }
```

Output for all of them

```css
.item1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.item2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.item3 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.item4 { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

The method used is called [interpolation #{}](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: Can this same approach be used with the percentage sign? SCSS seems to grumble...

Comment: For the percentage sign you have to use the interpolation method as well, so for example `#{(24px / 16px)}#{"%"}` will output `1.5%`

Comment: You should NEVER EVER EVER do this.  Ever.  Under any circumstance.  This will always give you a string, meaning you will never be able to use the result in a later mathematical operation.

Comment: Sass lead designer here! @cimmanon is right; this isn't a robust or idiomatic way of converting units. Sass's units are part of its arithmetic, and working with the unit arithmetic will help produce better, more maintainable stylesheets.

Comment: For percentage you could alternatively use `#{(24px / 16px)}unquote("%")`

Comment: @NatalieWeizenbaum So what's your suggestion? Never appending units after variable sizes?

Answer (score 6):

I assume the reason you're asking this is because, in the surrounding context, 1 em = 16 px, and you want to use this relationship to convert the target font size from pixels to ems.

If so, the *right* thing to do is to multiply the font size with the scaling factor 1em / 16px, like this:

```
$h1-font-size: 24px;
$body-font-size: 16px;

$body-em-scale: 1em / $body-font-size;

h1 {
  font-size: $h1-font-size * $body-em-scale;  // -> 1.5em
}
```

or just:

```
h1 {
  font-size: $h1-font-size * (1em / $body-font-size);  // -> 1.5em
}
```

This is exactly how it works in physics, too: if have, say, 50 [moles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) of water, and you want to know how much that weighs in [grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_(unit)), you multiply the amount of water you have (= 50 mol) with the [molar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) of water (≈ 18 g/mol) to find out that your sample of water weighs 50 mol × 18 g/mol ≈ 900 grams.  Converting pixels to ems in SASS works just the same way: first find out how many ems there are per pixel, in the context you intend to use the rule in, and then multiply the size in px with that ratio, expressed in units of em/px.

---

Ps. Of course, if the units you were converting between had a fixed ratio that SASS already knew about, then you could simply let it do the conversion automatically for you, using the "zero plus trick".  For example, if you wanted to convert the font size from px to cm, you could simply do:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 0cm + $h1-font-size;  // -> 0.635cm
}
```

This works because SASS allows you to add together two values given in compatible units (like px and cm), and will express the result in the same units as the *first* value in the sum.  The reason this trick *doesn't* work for px -> em is that here the conversion factor is not fixed, but depends on the surrounding context, and so SASS doesn't know how to do the conversion automatically.

Comment: So in other words, this question is a duplicate of an existing question?  (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513395/adding-a-unit-to-a-number-in-sass)

Comment: @cimmanon: Not exactly. That question asks how to append a unit to a unitless number. This one is asking how to convert a size measure between two different units (px -> em).

Comment: We already have a question about stripping units, too (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328259/how-do-you-strip-the-unit-from-any-number-in-sass)

Comment: @cimmanon: The point I'm trying to make is that stripping and appending units willy-nilly is *wrong* here. The units are there [for a reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), and you really should work *with them*, not just use hacks to strip them before doing math and then stick them back on again. And the proper way to convert between two units that don't have a fixed ratio is to find out the correct conversion ratio for your case and multiply by it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to add a unit, is to use `... * 1em` or `... + 0em` where `em` is the unit you want to get:

```
font-size: (24px/16px) + 0em; // ... + 0px for px
//or
font-size: (24px/16px) * 1em; 
//both produce: font-size: 1.5em;
```

This way, it will remain as a **number** so you can use it in math operations or other functions.

But if you want the result as a string or don't care the numeric value of result for some reason, you can also simply get it this way:

```
font-size: (24px/16px) + em; //font-size: 1.5em; //em does not include quotations
```

no need to use `unquote` or `#{}` here (as written in other answers)!