# Adding a unit to a number in Sass

Tags: sass

I am trying to create dynamic values, but have failed so far. The created pixel value seems to lose the ability to be used in calculations.

```
$numericValue: 30;

$pixelValue: $numericValue+px;
// also tried $pixelValue: #{$numericValue}px;

$calc: $pixelValue * 2;
// also tried $calc: unquote($pixelValue) * 2;
```

This throws an error

Syntax error: Undefined operation: "30px times 2"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The trick is to use `* 1px` when you want to add a unit. Using `+px` or interpolation (`#{$numericValue}px`) turns it into a string.

```
$numericValue: 30;

$pixelValue: $numericValue * 1px;

$calc: $pixelValue * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the unit you will use. If you are working with pixels you can create dynamic values adding `px` to the `$numericValue`.

```
$numericValue: 30px;
$pixelValue: $numericValue;
$calc: $pixelValue * 2;
```