# Css sprite in div with width %?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, liquid-layout

Is possible to have an image of Css sprite in `div` with `width` in % ?

Now i tried this but not works:

```
.sprite-gloss-vulc {
    background-image: url("/images/sprite-img.png");
}

.sprite-gloss-vulc-anello { 
  background-position: -1px -0px; 
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px; 
}

#flex {
 width: 17%;
}

img {
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px; 
}


<div id="flex">
    <img src="/images/transparent.gif" class="sprite-gloss-vulc sprite-gloss-vulc-anello">
</div>
```

When the width of div parent is bigger than 120px (width `img`) works, but if i resize the page the css sprite is "cut". 
Is cut because the news width of div it is smaller, but sizes `.sprite-gloss-vulc-anello` they are still the same.

I hope you can forgive me for my english and help me....
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [responsive sprites / percentages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810262/responsive-sprites-percentages)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving height width and twice to `img` tag and the class

```
.sprite-gloss-vulc {
    background-image: url("/images/sprite-img.png");
}

.sprite-gloss-vulc-anello { 
  background-position: -1px -0px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

#flex {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use sprite image with percentage.

You can add max-width property to sprite-gloss-vulc-anello or img tag but i wont work either.

If you want to resize image dynamically based on parent div you should use it as a seperate image file.