# How to use math.sqrt in SCSS with string value

Tags: sass, compass-sass, scss-mixins

I use SCSS and have 2 functions:

```
@function get-size-in-units($size, $unit: px) {
  @return #{$size}#{$unit};
}

@function get-container-size($side) {
   @return math.ceil(math.sqrt(2 * math.pow($side, 2)));
 }
```

And now i use it like this:

```
get-size-in-units(get-container-size(40));
```

Now I have a need for the function `get-container-size` to work with string value. I mean I want to call it with `'40px'`, `'40rem'` and etc, not with `40`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to strip `units` from `$side` for that create a `@function`.

```scss
@use 'sass:math';

@function stripUnit($number) {
    @return math.div($number, ($number * 0 + 1));
}
```

Credits for `stripUnit` function goes to [Kitty Giraudel](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/strip-unit-function/)
 and [Miriam Suzanne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12335841/15748278).

Now use the returned `value` in your `@function`

```scss
@function get-container-size($side) {
    @return math.ceil(math.sqrt(2 * math.pow(stripUnit($side), 2)));
}
```

**Complete Code**

```scss
@use 'sass:math';

@function stripUnit($number) {
    @return math.div($number, ($number * 0 + 1));
}

@function get-container-size($side) {
    @return math.ceil(math.sqrt(2 * math.pow(stripUnit($side), 2)));
}

@function get-size-in-units($size, $unit: px) {
    @return #{$size}#{$unit};
}
```

Then you can use it like :

```
.container {
    width: get-size-in-units(get-container-size(40px));
}
```